# weird logic problem, self reference

Tags: logic

http://www.folj.com/puzzles/difficult-logic-problems.htm

The Most Intelligent Prince

the solution says it must be white. but wouldn't the other 2 prince think of the same thing and deduce their hat is also white, contradicting the assumption that they can't deduce? this question feels self referential.

also, assume you are wearing black. the other two prince A and B will see a black-white combo. A sees B can't deduce so he can't be black and must be white. but B will think of the same thing and also conclude he is white. but again this contradicts the assumption that A & B can't deduce their colour.

Is this question self referential and flawed?

Comment: Do I have to click into your link to find out what the problem is?

Comment: Better question: *Why* do we have to click the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is problem solving speed involved in the answer. The solution relies on the assumption that you know how fast the other two would have solved the problem if you were wearing a black hat - and then failing to solve it by then would be enough to deduce that you've got a white hat.

I think the problem is a bit flawed because there's no reliable information about that.

On the other hand the fairness alone of the task is enough to deduce that everyone would need to wear a white hat. See if there were two black hat the one with a white hat would have a definitive advantage - so by fairness that's out of the question, and with that out of the question also one black hat would give the ones with white hat an advantage - so by fairness that's also out of the question. This solution is not about timing - you should be able to tell blindfolded by this argument.

Answer (score 1):

If any prince sees two black hats, that prince would instantly deduce that his own hat was white, and would immediately announce it.

Since there was no such announcement, every prince knows that there is at most one black hat.

Thus, if any prince *sees* one black hat, he can deduce that it's the only one, hence his own hat must be white, and he would quickly announce it.

Since there was no such announcement, it should have become clear to each prince that there are *no* black hats.

They all should have realized this, but apparently only one of them was bold enough of to take the chance that there wasn't some kind of error due to slow reaction or lack of logic on the part of the others.